# Pay with Debit or Credit Card - The button is not displayed

Tags: paypal, credit-card

Here is a tutorial: https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-standard-payment-gateway-integration-php/
Below is a button. If I click the paypal gate will appear. There is also a button: "Pay with Debit or Credit Card"
When I write a code according to the tutorial, I do not have a paypal button on the sandbox: "Pay with Debit or Credit Card"
I only have the button: "Create an Account"
Where is the problem?

Comment: Guest Checkout requirements???
- confirmed email
- Verify your PayPal accoun

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if your PayPal account is Business/Premier.

```
Then check for the PayPal account optional setting is "on or off". It should be on.

Login to PayPal
Go to your Account Profile.
Select: My Selling Tools
Under: Selling Online
Locate: Website Preferences
Click on: Update
Locate: PayPal Account Optional
Click:  On
Click: Save
```

Please contact PayPal customer care support and check your country is supported with guest checkout or not.